# Module to highlight the source code shown in a node

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, source-highlighting

What are the possible module candidates for highlighting the source code shown in a node? Is there any module that does the task using Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently use [GeSHi Filter for syntax highlighting](https://www.drupal.org/project/geshifilter) for my personal code dumping ground and found it pretty useful. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> The GeShi Filter module provides a filter for source code syntax highlighting for a wide range of languages.
>
> Source code can be entered with for example `<code type="java">...</code>` or `<blockcode language="python">...</blockcode>`. Starting from version 5.x-2.0 it is also possible to define your own generic and language specific tags (e.g. `<java>`) or to work with square bracket style tags (e.g. `[python]`). Automatically adding line numbers is possible too with for example `[ruby linenumbers="normal"]`.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Chili Highlighter](http://drupal.org/project/chili_highlighter), which allows to highlight code from browser side.